# Powershell timer doesnt seem to call function

Tags: windows, powershell, timer

Here is my code to send an alert if there has been no file activity to a folder in the last ten minutes:

```
$folderToMonitor = "my\target\folder"
$script:alertThreshold = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10)
$script:lastFileEventTime = (Get-Date)

# Function to send alert
function SendAlert {
    # Code to send alert (e.g., send email, log alert, etc.)
    Write-Host "SendAlert"
}

# Function to monitor folder for file events
function MonitorFolder {
    write-host "im in the monitorfolder function"
    $currentDateTime = Get-Date
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderToMonitor -File -Force
    $recentEvents = $files | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt $script:lastFileEventTime }

    if ($recentEvents.Count -eq 0) {
        # No recent file events, check if the alert threshold has been reached
        if ($currentDateTime -ge $script:alertThreshold) {
            # Send alert
            SendAlert
        }
    } else {
        # Reset the last file event time since a file event occurred
        $script:lastFileEventTime = $currentDateTime
    }
}
# Set up a timer to periodically monitor the folder
try {
    # Timer initialization code here
    $timer = New-Object System.Timers.Timer
    $timer.Interval = 6000  # Interval in milliseconds (60 seconds)

} catch {
    Write-Host "Timer initialization error: $_"
}

Write-Host "Registering timer event"
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -Action {
    MonitorFolder
    Write-Host "Timer elapsed event occurred"
}
Write-Host "Timer event registered"

# Start the timer
$timer.Start()
Write-Host "Timer started"


# Keep the script running
while ($true) {
    # This loop keeps the script running indefinitely
    wait-event -Timeout 1
}
```

for some reason I never see the output of the MonitorFolder function printed to the console when I run the powershell script. I never see the output of Write-Host "Timer elapsed event occurred" either. Help please?

Comment: What is `MonitorFolder` ? Seems like you have a typo there, should be `Hello` instead ;)

Comment: yeah let me fix that that isnt the actual issue. Thanks

Comment: yea but now there is no issue in your currently updated question: https://i.imgur.com/EvnufD4.png.

Comment: it isnt working for me. I'm changing the question to my complete code

Comment: ok, now my next question is why are you not using a [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-8.0) instead of this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue - your code works fine (although it gets stuck in a loop sending the same alert repeatedly if no new files appear)